# button is not working when pseudo element used for parent div

Tags: javascript, css

button is not working when pseudo element used for parent 
pls help I demonstrated the my work in the js fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/uv5u5rLk/

```
<div class="slide_wrapper">
    <!--Slide_area_start-->
<div class="slide_area ">
        <!--Slide_content_area_start-->
<div class="slide_content_area clearfix">
            <h1>Welcome to KBC</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<input type="button" class = "slide_content_button btn" >
<div class="slide_content_button btn" ><a href="#">Know More</a>      </div>
        </div>
        <!--Slide_content_area_end-->
</div>
    <!--Slide_area_end-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `z-index` in your `.slide_area` to `z-index:1`.

Don't use `z-index:-1`.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uv5u5rLk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean ?? what try to do with your button link your js code

if you want take input value for server side with php for e.g you need to put

```
<form method="your method" action="your action">


    <input name="yournameInput" ></input>
    <input name="yournameInput" ></input>
    <button id="mybtn" type="subcribe"></button>

</form>
```

that will subcribe on your form action

now if you want to do modification for client side use js

```
<script>
  var btn = document.getElementById('mybtn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    // your action
  });

</script>
```

sory for not hep usefull but your question is not clear